# Photos Gallery - Database Design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

This is my database design on photo gallery, I like feedback please or what can it be improved?

```
photos_category
- photocat_id (P)
- name
- slug
(5, 'Cars', 'cars')



photos_albums
- album_id (P)
- photocat_id (F)
- name
- description
- active
(20,5,'BMW','Nice BMW cars',1)

photos
- photos_id (P)
- album_id (F)
- image
(33,20,'bmw_car4.jpg')
```

bmw_car4.jpg is original size and it will be located at:
/gallery/original/bmw_car4.jpg

For frontend (resized):

Thumbnail: /gallery/thumbs/bmw_car4.jpg

Image: /gallery/images/bmw_car4.jpg

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your design seems quite correct to me :

- it's simple and functionnal,
- there is no duplication of information,
- and you can, from one object, find its related informations

I would just, if you plan on having a lot of photos, add some kind of sub-directories scheme, to avoid having too many files in a single directory *(`/gallery/original/`, and the directories for resized images)*.

You could add some hashing mecanism, based on the upload date *(month or day, depending on the amount of images)* of the images, or something like that.

For example, you could have :

- `/gallery/original/2011/01/` : all images uploaded in january
- `/gallery/original/2011/02/` : all images uploaded in february
- and so on

Then, you'll store the path in your `photos` table, and not only the file's name.

Comment: Thank you, sub-directories scheme is really good idea. I never thought of that. That should be easy. Should I add other field for path? photos.path (/2011/01/), photos.image (bmw_car4.jpg)

Comment: Having two different fields might be useful in some situations -- for instance, if you need to just display the name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Ooooh! Absolute must is to include a field in your image table that stores doctype. Its very handy for image retrieval and also if you forget to limit what files get uploaded, you can see at a glance which types are being uploaded that you don't want in there, and also which types you want to support and currently don't. I had people uploading word documents containing images you see, and I thought, "What the hey" and added support for them. Storing files outside the database is a great idea. I made the mistake of alt, name, description, created, last-modified in there when I used a database to actually store the images themselves, and the content size of the image data meant that getting the results was VERY SLOW. You've done a great job.